# decode_json_fields not moving data to root

Tags: filebeat, elastic-beats

We are using Winlogbeat to collect Event logs but rather than pull the data out of the `winlog` field, I want to move all the contents into the root field, which will help me automatically generate the fields I need.

```
processors:
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["winlog"]
      process_array: false
      max_depth: 1
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: true
      add_error_key: false

winlogbeat.event_logs:
  - name: Security
```

I've tried making the `processors` global as the above winlogbeat.yml, and moving it into the module. In both cases, it seems like the processor is completely ignored. Expected output is something like:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2022-06-14T13:41:01.532Z",
    "@metadata": {
        "beat": "winlogbeat",
        "type": "_doc",
        "version": "7.17.1"
    },
    "host": {
        "name": "xxxxx"
    },
    "ecs": {
        "version": "1.12.0"
    },
    "agent": {
        "hostname": "xxxxx",
        "ephemeral_id": "xxx-xxx-xxx",
        "id": "xxx-xxx-xxx",
        "name": "xxxxx",
        "type": "winlogbeat",
        "version": "7.17.1"
    
    "channel": "Security",
    "record_id": 12345,
    "provider_guid": "{xxx-xxx-xxx}",
    "api": "wineventlog",
    "computer_name": "xxxxx",
    "process": {
        "pid": 123,
        "thread": {
            "id": 1234
            }
        },
    "provider_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing",
    "keywords": [
        "Audit Success"
    ],
    "opcode": "Info",
    "task": "Logoff",
    "event_data": {
        "TargetUserName": "xxxxx$",
        "TargetDomainName": "xxxxx",
        "TargetLogonId": "xxxxxx",
        "LogonType": "3",
        "TargetUserSid": "S-1-5-18"
    },
        "event_id": "4634"
    },
    "event": {
        "code": "4634",
        "kind": "event",
        "provider": "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing",
        "outcome": "success",
        "action": "Logoff",
        "created": "2022-06-14T13:41:03.201Z"
    },
    "log": {
        "level": "information"
    }}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do max_depth: 2 or changing the array values?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer eventually. The field that `json_decode_field` takes has to be a string. I was able to get it working by converting the field to a string before `json_decode_field`.

```
- convert:
    fields:
      - {from: "winlog", type: "string"}
- decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["winlog"]...
```